# Is it good idea to create this same instance in one page class in UWP?

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

Sometimes when i wrote i had to eg edit a text in TextBlock which is on other Page, then I did this trick:

```
    private static MainPage _gui;

    public static void SetTitleText(string text) => _gui.TitleText.Text = text;

    public static Visibility InfoCenterStackPanelVisibility
    {
        get { return _gui.InfoCenterStackPanel.Visibility; }
        set { _gui.InfoCenterStackPanel.Visibility = value; }
    }

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        _gui = this;
    }
```

And in other page i just call `MainPage.SetTitleText` etc;

And I want to know, is any other, better way to acces these items, without creating `_gui`?

ps I looked for any likely looking topics, I did not found an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally this is a bad idea because if your app gets complex enough you will end up in a situation where your `MainPage` doesn't exist at runtime, and thus will crash when you try and access the (null) static instance. This could happen eg if you implement Suspend / Terminate / Resume in a multi-page app, or you implement a contract like Share. Even if your current project is simple, this is a bad habit to get into if you build larger apps in the future.

Typically you would use an [MVVM approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93viewmodel) to have this information in your data model, and then the `MainPage` would just bind to the data model (or explicitly read values out of it). There are a lot of web resources for MVVM - just use your favourite search engine.

Comment: Thanks a lot for an answer, now i know what to learn next :)
Have a nice day